# Can I enable "Hey Siri" only when using AirPods?

Tags: siri

I have "Hey Siri" turned on so I can use my phone hands-free when my AirPods are in (if I'm running, washing dishes, etc.). But I'd prefer not to have it listening all the time.

Is there a way to configure "Hey Siri" so it only listens through AirPods, but is otherwise disabled?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t appear that is a feature that can be enabled only on the AirPods. According to the [support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/airpods/set-up-siri-devc2c0f438a/1.0/web/1.0#dev52d7209e8) it must be enabled on whatever device (iPhone, Mac, etc) they are connected to to work.

According to Apple all dictation is processed locally on device though they do have a transcript log sent to Apple with a random identifier assigned. This is different than the audio recordings you can opt in allowing in the Analytics & Improvement setting’s page. You can delete request history associated by going to Settings > Siri & Search > Siri & Dictation History and tapping Delete Siri & Dictation History.